# How do I see a file's all historical version on Gitlab?

Tags: gitlab

First I thought this is a very simple issue. But after trying a lot of ways, I couldn't find a way to explore a file's all history versions on gitlab.com

What should I do?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

[Get file history](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/git_history.html), from UI after you click on file content you can click on **History button** in upper right corner.

Comment: When I clicked on an item in the commit list ( https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/img/file_history_output_v12_6.png ) , it shows all the files included in that batch. Is there a way to only show the very file?

Comment: Ok, so you wanted besides commits limited to changes to file also only diffs related to this particular file. I couldn't find such an option on GitLab page. Maybe I'm missing something though.

Answer (score 1):

That's not directly in gitLab but I guess it's totaly what's you need.
You can have the state of one file at each commit in visual code with GitLens widget.

see more :  **VS Code tips — Viewing file history with GitLens :  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bRdQw4-sGIY**

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps :-

1. Open your project on gitlab.
2. Click on repository.
3. Click on files
4. Go to Find File search box on the right side and search for filename.
5. Click on history tab, list of all commits on that file will be there.

[Snapshots for reference is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ez3w.png)

Answer (score 0):

To view a previous version of a document:

1. go to the file in gitlab.
2. choose the 'History' tab.This will show the commit history of the file.
3. on the far right of the commit you'd like to go back to, you can select a little folder icon that is labeled 'Browse File'. Choose this to view the entire file state for the commit.The icon is next to the commit hash ID.
   [image]